# Ruby Daemons will not start

Tags: ruby, rubygems, daemon

I am using the ruby daemons gem to create a custom daemon for my rails project.  The only problem is that when I try to start the daemons `ruby lib/daemons/test_ctl start` that it fails and will not start. The log file has this output.

```
# Logfile created on Wed Oct 22 16:14:23 +0000 2008 by /  
*** below you find the most recent exception thrown, this will be likely (but not certainly) the exception that made the application exit abnormally \*\*\*  
# MissingSourceFile: no such file to load -- utf8proc_native  
*** below you find all exception objects found in memory, some of them may have been thrown in your application, others may just be in memory because they are standard exceptions ***  
# NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory>  
# SystemStackError: stack level too deep>  
# fatal: exception reentered>  
# LoadError: no such file to load -- daemons>  
# LoadError: no such file to load -- active_support>  
# MissingSourceFile: no such file to load -- lib/string>  
# MissingSourceFile: no such file to load -- utf8proc_native>
```

It even happens when I generate a daemon (from the rails plugin) and try to run it.  Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I actually found the answer to this problem.  I require two custom files in the `config/environment.rb`.  I used relative path names and because the daemons are executed in the rails main directory it could not find these two files.  after making them absolute path it fixed the problem.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by adding this line before the Daemons.run line:
`$: << Dir.pwd`
This explicitly adds the current working directory to Ruby's include path. For some reason, this is necessary when using the daemons library; the include path looked fine, but didn't work 'til I added this.

Comment: Update: I still ran into include errors. Switching from using Daemons.run to Daemons.run_proc fixed my wagon. Here's how to create a daemon script this way:

`require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'
pwd = Dir.pwd
Daemons.run_proc('yourserver.rb') do
  Dir.chdir(pwd)
  exec "ruby yourserver.rb'
end`

Comment: 'require_relative' instead of 'require' works as well

Answer (score 1):

I just spent 30 minutes trying to solve a similar error when trying to get daemons plugin working:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- active_support
```

For some reason, it wasn't finding `active_support` lib, even though it was installed. (Perhaps due to me having frozen rails).
In my case, the solution to this was to use the absolute path for active_support in my
ctl file (eg `lib/daemons/mailer_ctl`).

I needed to change line 5 from:

```
   require 'active_support'
```

to

```
 require './vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support.rb'
```